# What is the right way to implement classes as a component in .Net Core?

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, interface, components, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to implement some providers in my code. Now, providers can be different types. For example a provider can fetch a url, read some xml and parse it with a given parser as a component as well. A parser can be xml parser, json parser or some other parser in the future. And a reader can read from a given url or can read from a file and so on.

I'm using .net core 2.0 and dependency injection to achieve this. So far i wrote the code below.

**Setup Dependencies**

```
    var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddLogging()
        .AddSingleton<App>()
        .AddSingleton<IProviderService, ProviderService>()
        .AddScoped<IFileReader, FileReader>()
        .AddScoped<IWebReader, WebReader>()
        .BuildServiceProvider();
```

**Provider Class**

```
public class Provider: IProvider
{
    private IReader reader;

    public Provider(IReader reader)
    {
        this.reader = reader;
    }

    public string Start()
    {
        return reader.Read();
    }
}
```

**Provider Service**

```
    public class ProviderService : IProviderService
    {
        private readonly IWebReader webReader;
        private readonly IFileReader fileReader;

        public ProviderService(IWebReader webReader, IFileReader fileReader)
        {
            this.webReader = webReader;
            this.fileReader = fileReader;
        }

        public List<IProvider> GetProviders()
        {
            return new List<IProvider>() {
                new Provider(webReader),
                new Provider(fileReader),
                new Provider(webReader)
            };
        }
    }
```

**Reader Interface**

```
    public interface IReader
    {
        string Read();
    }
```

**File Reader**

```
    public interface IFileReader : IReader
    {}

    public class FileReader : IFileReader
    {
        public string Read()
        {
            return "Got data from file (txt)";
        }
    }
```

**Web Reader**

```
    public interface IWebReader : IReader
    {}

    public class WebReader : IWebReader
    {
        public string Read()
        {
            return "Got data from web (www)";
        }
    }
```

**App**

```
    public class App
    {
        private readonly IProviderService providerService;

        public App(IProviderService providerService)
        {
            this.providerService = providerService;
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            var providerList = providerService.GetProviders();

            providerList.ForEach((provider) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(provider.Start());
            });

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Now i can change the reader in the provider and i will implement parsers in the same way above in the reader. However i need to pass url to the web reader and for example file path to the file reader. And there can be other properties for a specific reader. How can i send them to the reader? I'm sure i'm doing something wrong but i can't figure out my mistake. Can you help me?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question, because the answer seems rather obvious. You would of course pass the filepath/URL as a parameter to the `Read` method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I thought that but if you look at my Provider Service readers are given through injection. So i couldn't call them with  constructor parameters. Or maybe i shouldn't give them through injection?

Comment: That's exactly why it should be passed as a parameter to `Read`. The class can read from any source, presumably, so it would be a mistake to make the source part of the construction, as now you're limiting it to one very narrow usage. Rather, by passing to `Read` method, when you actually want to read something, you can read from any number of different sources, all with the same instance.